# Make divs as block elements only on mobile devices

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How can i make these two `.col-md-3` and `.col-md-6` divs as block elements, to get one under another, if user is viewing the site on mobile device?

Is there a jQuery solution for this?

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3 fejlec_logo">
      <a title="<?php echo $siteName; ?>" class="navbar-brand logo clearfix" href="<?php echo $host; ?>">
        Site logo
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 fejlec_kereses">
      <form role="search" name="header_search_form" id="header_search_form" method="post">
        <div class="input-group stylish-input-group bc-wrapper">
          <input type="text" class="form-control header_search_input" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Termékek keresése..." name="search_input" id="country_id" onkeyup="autocomplet();">
          <span class="input-group-addon">
                                <button name="search_submit" type="submit" class="header_search_button"><i class="fa fa-search header_search_icon" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>  
                            </span>
        </div>
        <div class="bc-menu list-group" id="country_list_id"></div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: anchor tag `class="navbar-brand logo clearfix"` breaks the grid layout. By default class `col-xs-12` is applied to cell, so you don't (even should not) need to apply it clearly. All you need is to define `.fejlec_logo { overflow: hidden; }`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `col-xs-12` along with `col-md-6` , `xs` means extra small this class will work only when the document window reaches the small devices

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-12 fejlec_logo">
            <a title="<?php echo $siteName; ?>" class="navbar-brand logo clearfix" href="<?php echo $host; ?>"><?php echo $siteName; ?></a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12 fejlec_kereses">
            <form role="search" name="header_search_form" id="header_search_form" method="post">
                <div class="input-group stylish-input-group bc-wrapper">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control header_search_input" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Termékek keresése..." name="search_input" id="country_id" onkeyup="autocomplet();" >
                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                        <button name="search_submit" type="submit" class="header_search_button"><i class="fa fa-search header_search_icon" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>  
                    </span>
                </div>
                <div class="bc-menu list-group" id="country_list_id"></div>                    
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Also, keep in mind that Bootstrap Grid System requires a `.container` or `.container-fluid` div to be parent of the first `.row` in your structure. Learn more about this [here](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid). I have added this in the edit of your question.

Answer (score 1):

*Add* class `col-xs-12` to their tags (add, not replace - that way it will stay as is on medium and larger screens)

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3 fejlec_logo">
      <a title="<?php echo $siteName; ?>" class="navbar-brand logo clearfix" href="<?php echo $host; ?>">
        Site logo
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 fejlec_kereses">
      <form role="search" name="header_search_form" id="header_search_form" method="post">
        <div class="input-group stylish-input-group bc-wrapper">
          <input type="text" class="form-control header_search_input" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Termékek keresése..." name="search_input" id="country_id" onkeyup="autocomplet();">
          <span class="input-group-addon">
                                <button name="search_submit" type="submit" class="header_search_button"><i class="fa fa-search header_search_icon" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>  
                            </span>
        </div>
        <div class="bc-menu list-group" id="country_list_id"></div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```